# Selecting static ROI

Tags: python, opencv

I was following this tutorial
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/
and you choose the ROI by pausing the video with S and then making a window on the object you want to track

What I need help in is::

1. I want to choose the object without pausing the video nor selecting a window I mean the selection window is static and I just click left click to track
2. every time I click right click on another object it deletes the previous one and track the new object
3. control the selection window size by the mouse wheel|
   here is the code I'm using now

```html
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import serial

arduino=serial.Serial('com51', 115200)
# Serial write section

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str,
 help="path to input video file")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--tracker", type=str, default="kcf",
 help="OpenCV object tracker type")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# extract the OpenCV version info
(major, minor) = cv2.__version__.split(".")[:2]
 
# if we are using OpenCV 3.2 OR BEFORE, we can use a special factory
# function to create our object tracker
if int(major) == 3 and int(minor) < 3:
 tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(args["tracker"].upper())
 
# otherwise, for OpenCV 3.3 OR NEWER, we need to explicity call the
# approrpiate object tracker constructor:
else:
 # initialize a dictionary that maps strings to their corresponding
 # OpenCV object tracker implementations
 OPENCV_OBJECT_TRACKERS = {
  "csrt": cv2.TrackerCSRT_create,
  "kcf": cv2.TrackerKCF_create,
  "boosting": cv2.TrackerBoosting_create,
  "mil": cv2.TrackerMIL_create,
  "tld": cv2.TrackerTLD_create,
  "medianflow": cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create,
  "mosse": cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create
 }
 
 # grab the appropriate object tracker using our dictionary of
 # OpenCV object tracker objects
 tracker = OPENCV_OBJECT_TRACKERS[args["tracker"]]()
 
# initialize the bounding box coordinates of the object we are going
# to track
initBB = None
# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference to the web cam
if not args.get("video", False):
 print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
 vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
 time.sleep(1.0)
 
# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
 vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
 
 #if vs.isOpened(): 
    # get vs property 
#width2 = vs.get(3)
#height2 = vs.get(4)


# initialize the FPS throughput estimator
fps = None
# loop over frames from the video stream
while True:
 # grab the current frame, then handle if we are using a
 # VideoStream or VideoCapture object
 frame = vs.read()
 frame = frame[1] if args.get("video", False) else frame
 
 # check to see if we have reached the end of the stream
 if frame is None:
  break
 
 # resize the frame (so we can process it faster) and grab the
 # frame dimensions
 #frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1280)
 (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
 # check to see if we are currently tracking an object
 if initBB is not None:
  # grab the new bounding box coordinates of the object
  (success, box) = tracker.update(frame)
 
  # check to see if the tracking was a success
  if success:
   (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
   cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),
    (0, 255, 0), 2)                                
  # update the FPS counter
  fps.update()
  fps.stop()
  #fixing the x,y tracker box center
  x2=int(x+w/2)
  y2=int(y+h/2)
  #the offsets for the x,y tracking from the center
  sox = str(x2 - (W/2))
  soy = str((H/2) - y2)
  #sending the offsets to arduino
  arduino.write('x'.encode())
  arduino.write(sox.encode())
  #print ("offset X value sent: ")
  #print (sox)
  #time.sleep(0.01)
  arduino.write('y'.encode())
  arduino.write(soy.encode())
  #print ("offset Y value sent : ")
  #print (soy)
  #time.sleep(0.01)
  cv2.line(frame, (int(W/2), int(H/2)), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
  cv2.line(frame, (int(W), int(H/2)), (0, int(H/2)), (0, 0, 0), 2)
  cv2.line(frame, (int(W/2), int(H)), (int(W/2), 0), (0, 0, 0), 2)
  #cv2.line(frame, (320, 240), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
  
  # initialize the set of information we'll be displaying on
  # the frame
  info = [
        
   #("Tracker", args["tracker"]),
   #("X = ",str(x)),
   #("Y = ",str(y)),
   ("offset X = ",sox), 
   ("offset y = ",soy),
   #("width = ",W),
   #("height = ",H),
   ("FPS", "{:.2f}".format(fps.fps())),
   
  ]
 
  # loop over the info tuples and draw them on our frame
  for (i, (k, v)) in enumerate(info): 
   text = "{}: {}".format(k, v)
   cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, H - ((i * 20) + 20)),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
    
          
         

# show the output frame
 cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
 key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
 
 
 # if the 's' key is selected, we are going to "select" a bounding
 # box to track
 
 
     
 if key == ord("s"):
  # select the bounding box of the object we want to track (make
  # sure you press ENTER or SPACE after selecting the ROI)
  initBB = cv2.selectROI("Frame", frame, fromCenter=False,
   showCrosshair=True)
   
 
  # start OpenCV object tracker using the supplied bounding box
  # coordinates, then start the FPS throughput estimator as well
  tracker.init(frame, initBB)
  fps = FPS().start()
  
 # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
 elif key == ord("q"):
  break
# if we are using a webcam, release the pointer
if not args.get("video", False):
 vs.stop()
 
# otherwise, release the file pointer
else:
 vs.release()
 

# close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make a few changes to your code. First add this call-back function at the top of your code to inform openCV what to do when you click.

```
mouse_click = False
tracker_location = (0,0)
def click_track(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global mouse_click, tracker_location
    # if the left mouse button was clicked, change flag
    # Click is sensed as a button up
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        mouse_click = True
        tracker_location = (x,y)
```

Then before you start the while loop add this to start your display window with the ability to sense mouse click.

```
# Create a window for click detection 
cv2.namedWindow("Frame")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Frame", click_track)
```

Finally at the spot where select ROI was once was, replace it with a static ROI that only operates when the mouse click flag is true.

```
if mouse_click == True:
    # select the bounding box of the object we want to track (make
    # sure you press ENTER or SPACE after selecting the ROI)
    h , w, ch = frame.shape

    # initial ROI size
    ROI_size_x = 0.1 * w
    ROI_size_y = 0.1 * h

    # Adjust the size when object is near image border
    if( tracker_location[0] + ROI_size_x >= w):
        ROI_size_x = w - tracker_location[0]
    if( tracker_location[1] + ROI_size_y >= h):
        ROI_size_y = h - tracker_location[1]
    if( tracker_location[0] - ROI_size_x < 0):
        tracker_location[0] = 0
    if( tracker_location[1] - ROI_size_y < 0):
        tracker_location[1] = 0

    initBB = ( tracker_location[0] - ROI_size_x, tracker_location[1] - ROI_size_y, ROI_size_x * 2,ROI_size_y * 2)
```

You can change the size of the static ROI with any value you like. Currently its set as 20% of the image size at the center.

Here is the entire code

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import serial

mouse_click = False
tracker_location = (0,0)
def click_track(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global mouse_click, tracker_location

    tracker_location = (x,y)
    # if the left mouse button was clicked, change flag
    # Click is sensed as a button up
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        mouse_click = True



arduino=serial.Serial('com51', 115200)
# Serial write section



# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str,
    help="path to input video file")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--tracker", type=str, default="kcf",
    help="OpenCV object tracker type")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# extract the OpenCV version info
(major, minor) = cv2.__version__.split(".")[:2]

# if we are using OpenCV 3.2 OR BEFORE, we can use a special factory
# function to create our object tracker
if int(major) == 3 and int(minor) < 3:
    tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(args["tracker"].upper())

# otherwise, for OpenCV 3.3 OR NEWER, we need to explicity call the
# approrpiate object tracker constructor:
else:
    # initialize a dictionary that maps strings to their corresponding
    # OpenCV object tracker implementations
    OPENCV_OBJECT_TRACKERS = {
        "csrt": cv2.TrackerCSRT_create,
        "kcf": cv2.TrackerKCF_create,
        "boosting": cv2.TrackerBoosting_create,
        "mil": cv2.TrackerMIL_create,
        "tld": cv2.TrackerTLD_create,
        "medianflow": cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create,
        "mosse": cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create
    }

    # grab the appropriate object tracker using our dictionary of
    # OpenCV object tracker objects
    tracker = OPENCV_OBJECT_TRACKERS[args["tracker"]]()


# Create a window for click detection 
cv2.namedWindow("Frame")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Frame", click_track)


# initialize the bounding box coordinates of the object we are going
# to track
initBB = None
# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference to the web cam
if not args.get("video", False):
    print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    time.sleep(1.0)

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

 #if vs.isOpened(): 
    # get vs property 
#width2 = vs.get(3)
#height2 = vs.get(4)


# initialize the FPS throughput estimator
fps = None
# loop over frames from the video stream
while True:
    # grab the current frame, then handle if we are using a
    # VideoStream or VideoCapture object
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = frame[1] if args.get("video", False) else frame

    # check to see if we have reached the end of the stream
    if frame is None:
        break

    # resize the frame (so we can process it faster) and grab the
    # frame dimensions
    #frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1280)
    (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
    # check to see if we are currently tracking an object
    if initBB is not None:
        # grab the new bounding box coordinates of the object
        (success, box) = tracker.update(frame)

        # check to see if the tracking was a success
        if success:
            (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),
                (0, 255, 0), 2)                                
        # update the FPS counter
        fps.update()
        fps.stop()
        #fixing the x,y tracker box center
        x2=int(x+w/2)
        y2=int(y+h/2)
        #the offsets for the x,y tracking from the center
        sox = str(x2 - (W/2))
        soy = str((H/2) - y2)
        #sending the offsets to arduino
        arduino.write('x'.encode())
        arduino.write(sox.encode())
        #print ("offset X value sent: ")
        #print (sox)
        #time.sleep(0.01)
        arduino.write('y'.encode())
        arduino.write(soy.encode())
        #print ("offset Y value sent : ")
        #print (soy)
        #time.sleep(0.01)
        cv2.line(frame, (int(W/2), int(H/2)), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.line(frame, (int(W), int(H/2)), (0, int(H/2)), (0, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(frame, (int(W/2), int(H)), (int(W/2), 0), (0, 0, 0), 2)
        #cv2.line(frame, (320, 240), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)

        # initialize the set of information we'll be displaying on
        # the frame
        info = [

            #("Tracker", args["tracker"]),
            #("X = ",str(x)),
            #("Y = ",str(y)),
            ("offset X = ",sox), 
            ("offset y = ",soy),
            #("width = ",W),
            #("height = ",H),
            ("FPS", "{:.2f}".format(fps.fps())),

        ]

        # loop over the info tuples and draw them on our frame
        for (i, (k, v)) in enumerate(info): 
            text = "{}: {}".format(k, v)
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, H - ((i * 20) + 20)),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)


    # select the bounding box of the object we want to track (make
    # sure you press ENTER or SPACE after selecting the ROI)
    h , w, ch = frame.shape

    # initial ROI size
    ROI_size_x = 0.1 * w
    ROI_size_y = 0.1 * h

    # Adjust the size when object is near image border
    if( tracker_location[0] + ROI_size_x >= w):
        ROI_size_x = w - tracker_location[0]
    if( tracker_location[1] + ROI_size_y >= h):
        ROI_size_y = h - tracker_location[1]
    if( tracker_location[0] - ROI_size_x < 0):
        tracker_location[0] = 0
    if( tracker_location[1] - ROI_size_y < 0):
        tracker_location[1] = 0

    initBB = ( tracker_location[0] - ROI_size_x, tracker_location[1] - ROI_size_y, ROI_size_x * 2,ROI_size_y * 2)
    #initBB = cv2.selectROI("Frame", frame, fromCenter=False,
    #   showCrosshair=True)

    if mouse_click == True:
        # start OpenCV object tracker using the supplied bounding box
        # coordinates, then start the FPS throughput estimator as well
        tracker = OPENCV_OBJECT_TRACKERS[args["tracker"]]()
        tracker.init(frame, initBB)
        fps = FPS().start()
        mouse_click = False

    #drawing the initial box
    cv2.rectangle(frame,int(initBB[0],initBB[1]),int(initBB[2],initBB[3]),(0,255,255),2)

    # show the output frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF



    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
# if we are using a webcam, release the pointer
if not args.get("video", False):
    vs.stop()

# otherwise, release the file pointer
else:
    vs.release()


# close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: thank you very mush yapws just to make sure is the static fixed size selection window square is following the mouse pointer ?

Comment: do you required it to do so?

Comment: yes of-course and without pressing enter or space after the selection just a left click to choose what you want to track and the selection window size is fixed but moving with the mouse pointer all the time

Comment: i tried what is above without errors but it is not working if you can post the whole code after editing one shot so i dont make mistakes in editing the code

Comment: how did it not work?  i need more information to help.

Comment: i added the code but it is giving me error here  h , w, ch = frame.shape
if you can edit the whole code and post it it will be better so i dont make mistake while upgrading it

Comment: now there is no errors i made it exactly the same as you told me the video starts but when i click i see nothing is going on

Comment: thank you man for your patient it is not giving any errors now but it is not working i think because it is not graping the mouse click position because i tried to print the array location tracker_location[0] and the it appears to be 0 even when i click with the mouse

Comment: I made some edits on the mousecallback function to enable the variables to be global

Comment: now lets go to the next question which is 
every time I click left click on another object it deletes the previous one and track a new object ( with just another left click on another object) so every time you click on something it tracks it

Comment: isnt it doing that right now? If not explain more. and add pictures of the result by adding extra information on the original question

Comment: i made the video to explain what is going on
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rl0iqC2GwVw
 i hope everything is clear in the video :)
im clicking but i get no new tracking it continues tracking the same object
but in the same time the location array got the new numbers

Comment: It seems that the tracker is unable to initialize. Try adding. tracker = OPENCV_OBJECT_TRACKERS[args["tracker"]]()
Before tracker.init

Comment: Thank you man very mush now it is wonderful i will make a video while it is working

Comment: the last thing can i just show the selection square with a crosshair tied to mouse pointer while it is moving for better selection or may be if we can make something like this http://clipart-library.com/img/2103655.jpg the circle size is same size as the selection box (tangent from inside ) whenever you change the 0.1 you made before it is going to make the selection box and crosshair circle bigger or smaller

Comment: I made changes to the code to draw a box when your mouse is hovering on the image. As for the cross-chair, i think i have teach you enough to run this project on your own. ^^. With a slight tweak, you can adjust the size of the box from your mouse as well.

Comment: yes you are right ok i will try to do the crosshair and the other stuff no problem you made the hard stuff to me thank you man
but by the way im getting error now 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final01.py", line 202, in <module>
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(initBB[0],initBB[1]),(initBB[2],initBB[3]),(0,255,255),2)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Comment: just place int in front of (initBB[0],initBB[1]) and (init[2],init[3]) to change the float value to integer. And it would be great if you accept my post as the answer to your question.

Comment: it did work but gived me another error about the fps update

Comment: anyway no problem you are right you helped me a lot in this question thank you my friend i really appreciate your help by the way this is the first time i use stackoverflow